# BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher not working on Win10

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I have tried the sample code found at https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothadvertisement/. C#.
It uses the class BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher. I have built that on my machine and executed it. I start the advertisement in foreground (or background) and then start an app on my phone (LightBlue and BLE Scanner tried). My PC isn't seen (I do see other devices)
The same when I try to write similar code myself. I have also tried writing a GattServiceProvider implementing a number of services. When I publish that one, I do see the services on the phone, and can read and write to them. So yes, bluetooth IS enabled and working (to some extent) on my machine.
I have latest version of Win10, with Intel AC8265 (with latest Intel drivers). It supports Bluetooth 4.2.
So why can't I see the advertisement? There are no error messages at all and the callbacks reports the advertisement is started as it should.
I'm also a bit confused by the relation between the BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher and the GattServiceProvider. Both do "publish" and the GattServiceProvider seems to be able to announce itself. But there is no way to add CompanyId or ManufacturerData to it. Shouldn't both be used? And both working...

To be more specific, it looks like the GattServiceProvider does actual advertising, but only advertising the computer name, bt address and service guids. No CompanyId or ManufacturerData at all. Googling around I found some people claiming that Company Id isn't required in advertisement, and others saying it is (and has to be registered). If Microsoft is advertising without Company Id, then I guess it's allowed.

And I can kind of understand if I'm not allowed to advertise an Intel NUC as having a Company Id from a totally different company. But if that is the case, one would think that the BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher would give some error code when used on a Win10 machine?